# Insert value to particular instance in dictionary with python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, oop

I'd like to fill a dictionary with instances of class that each has list with messages by using for loop and if there is already instance with the same id then insert the message into its list.

The csv file I'm working with:

```
time,ID,TYPE,Source
2021-07-26T23:59:59.143,112233449955,TYPE1,SOURCE1
2021-07-26T23:59:57.146,112233449955,TYPE2,SOURCE3
2021-07-26T23:59:56.148,233445522112,TYPE1,SOURCE2
2021-07-26T23:59:55.120,333333333333,TYPE2,SOURCE2
2021-07-26T23:59:52.130,444444444444,TYPE1,SOURCE14
2021-07-26T23:59:51.132,333333333333,TYPE3,SOURCE4
```

My code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time', 'ID', 'TYPE', 'Source'])

    class MessageID:
        time = None
        myid = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.messages= []

    class Message:
        time = None
        myid = None
        mytype = None
        source = None

        def __init__(self, time, myid, mytype, source):
            self.time = time
            self.myid = myid
            self.mytype = mytype
            self.source= source


    MessageID_dictionary= {}
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
        newMessage = Message(row['time'], row['ID'], row['TYPE'], row['Source'])
    
        # is id already in dictionary? then add newMessage.__dict__ to the list of instance with the found id
        if newMessage.myid in MessageID_dictionary.keys():
            MessageID_dictionary[newMessage.myid] = [MessageID_dictionary[newMessage.myid], newMessage.__dict__]  #Here I do not know how to find the particular instance with the found id (newMessage.id) and append to its list but not directly to the dictionary to the instance of the MessageID's
            print('yes')
        #if there is not the found id then create the instance of MessageID, append the newMessage to list of the instance and add the instance to the dictionary
        else:
            newMessageID = MessageID()
            newMessageID.messages.append(newMessage.__dict__)
            MessageID_dictionary[newMessage.myid] = newMessage.__dict__
            print('no')
    
        print(MessageID.dictionary)
        print(newMessage.messages)
```

My question is if there is an option to find the particular instance with the specified id in a dictionary and append a value to its list?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sure, now it should be alright.

Comment: Could you also add a sample input and output

Comment: I reformat your code. Check it. Can you update your post with the output of  `df.head().to_dict()` as a sample of your dataframe, please?

Comment: I added example of the csv file I'm working with and pandas dataframes I create and from which I fill the attributes of class

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found the solution for my question and want to share it here. If there are any better approaches, please do not hesitate and share it here.

To the code that I posted above I had to add temporary variable, where I store the particular instance on defined position in dictionary:

```
MessageID_dictionary= {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    newMessage = Message(row['time'], row['ID'], row['TYPE'], row['Source'])

    # is id already in dictionary? then add newMessage.__dict__ to the list of instance with the found id - so I take the instance with the key that match the id and add to its list the newMessage.__dict__
    if newMessage.myid in MessageID_dictionary.keys():
    tempMsgID = MessageID_dictionary.get(newMessage.myid)
    tempMsgID.messages.append(newMessage.__dict__)
    print('yes')
    #if there is not the found id then create the instance of MessageID, append the newMessage to list of the instance and add the instance to the dictionary
    else:
        newMessageID = MessageID()
        newMessageID.messages.append(newMessage.__dict__)
        MessageID_dictionary[newMessage.myid] = newMessage.__dict__
        print('no')

    print(MessageID.dictionary)
    print(newMessage.messages)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some stuff I dont get like the `time` and `miId` field in the Message class that you don't do anything with, but I think this is what you are looking for

```py
from collections import defaultdict

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time', 'ID', 'TYPE', 'Source'])


class MessageID:
    time = None
    myid = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.messages = []


class Message:
    time = None
    myid = None
    mytype = None
    source = None

    def __init__(self, time, myid, mytype, source):
        self.time = time
        self.myid = myid
        self.mytype = mytype
        self.source = source


MessageID_dictionary = defaultdict(MessageID)
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    newMessage = Message(row['time'], row['ID'], row['TYPE'], row['Source'])
    MessageID_dictionary[newMessage.myid].messages.append(newMessage.__dict__)
```

At the end of this code, `MessageID_dictionary` will be a dict where keys are the message ids, and the values are `MessageID` instances with matching `Message` in their `messages` field

Also, you might want to avoid iterrows() and use this

```py
def create_messageID(group_df):
    new_message = MessageID()
    new_message.messages = group_df.to_dict()
    return new_message

MessageID_dictionary = df.groupby('ID').apply(create_messageID).to_dict()
```